# ToggleButton и контекстное меню

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь сделать корректную работу ToggleButton.При нажатии открываю окно, при клике на другую область формы (или же при выборе вариантов) меню собственно закрывается, но если снова нажать на кнопку то она ничего не делает, то есть не отображает контектсное меню, после чего (еще раз нажав) снова его отображает.

Что я должна сделать, чтобы при повторном использовании кнопка снова отображала мое меню?

Код xaml

```
<ToggleButton Width="99"
                  Height="78"
                  Margin="58,-3,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Checked="bnetbutton_Click"
                  Style="{StaticResource NewBnetBtnStyle}">

        <ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Margin="10,10,10,10"
                         Style="{StaticResource Cm}">
                <MenuItem x:Name="accountMenu"
                          Click="LkButton_OnClick"
                          FontFamily="/Launcher;component/Resources/#Blizzard"
                          FontSize="13"
                          Header="Управление учетной записью"
                          Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}">
                    <MenuItem.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"
                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                           RadiusX="2"
                                           RadiusY="2"
                                           Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                           StrokeThickness="1" />
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                                          MinWidth="24"
                                                          SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />

                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                                      Margin="1"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                                      ContentSource="Icon"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}"
                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Bg" Property="Fill" Value="#FF323945" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.Template>
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="16"
                               Height="16"
                               Source="/Launcher;component/Resources/icon_manage_character_on.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem x:Name="supportMenu"
                          Click="ForumButton_OnClick"
                          FontFamily="/Launcher;component/Resources/#Blizzard"
                          FontSize="13"
                          Header="Служба поддержки"
                          Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}">
                    <MenuItem.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"
                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                           RadiusX="2"
                                           RadiusY="2"
                                           Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                           StrokeThickness="1" />
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                                          MinWidth="24"
                                                          SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                                      Margin="1"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                                      ContentSource="Icon"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}"
                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Bg" Property="Fill" Value="#FF323945" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.Template>
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="16"
                               Height="16"
                               Source="/Launcher;component/Resources/icon_menuSupport_on.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem x:Name="settingsMenu"
                          Click="SettinsButton_Click"
                          FontFamily="/Launcher;component/Resources/#Blizzard"
                          FontSize="13"
                          Header="Настройки"
                          Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}">
                    <MenuItem.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"
                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                           RadiusX="2"
                                           RadiusY="2"
                                           Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                           StrokeThickness="1" />
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                                          MinWidth="24"
                                                          SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                                      Margin="1"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                                      ContentSource="Icon"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}"
                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Bg" Property="Fill" Value="#FF323945" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.Template>
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="16"
                               Height="16"
                               Source="/Launcher;component/Resources/icon_menuSettings_on.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>

                <Separator />

                <MenuItem x:Name="reloginMenu"
                          Click="MenuItem_Click"
                          FontFamily="/Launcher;component/Resources/#Blizzard"
                          FontSize="13"
                          Header="Сменить пользователя"
                          Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}">
                    <MenuItem.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"
                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                           RadiusX="2"
                                           RadiusY="2"
                                           Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                           StrokeThickness="1" />
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                                          MinWidth="24"
                                                          SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                                      Margin="1"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                                      ContentSource="Icon"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}"
                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Bg" Property="Fill" Value="#FF323945" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.Template>
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="16"
                               Height="16"
                               Source="/Launcher;component/Resources/icon_menusignout_on.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <!--  Template="{StaticResource contextMenuItemTemplate}"  -->
                <MenuItem x:Name="exitMenu"
                          Click="MenuItem_Click_1"
                          FontFamily="/Launcher;component/Resources/#Blizzard"
                          FontSize="13"
                          Header="Выход"
                          Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}">
                    <MenuItem.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Bg"
                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                           RadiusX="2"
                                           RadiusY="2"
                                           Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                           StrokeThickness="1" />
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                                          MinWidth="24"
                                                          SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                                      Margin="1"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                                      ContentSource="Icon"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}"
                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Bg" Property="Fill" Value="#FF323945" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.Template>
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="16"
                               Height="16"
                               Source="/Launcher;component/Resources/icon_menuExit_on.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>

            </ContextMenu>
        </ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
    </ToggleButton>
```

Код c#

```
private void bnetbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        (sender as ToggleButton).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
        (sender as ToggleButton).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (sender as ToggleButton);
        (sender as ToggleButton).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
        (sender as ToggleButton).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так происходит потому, что вы подписаны на событие Checked у ToggleButton, которое срабатывает при первом нажатии на кнопку. При втором срабатывает Unchecked. Ну и так по кругу. В зависимости от вашей ситуации вы можете решить задачу одним из способов:

1. Подписать ту же процедуру (bnetbutton_Click) на событие Unchecked.
2. Либо вместо событий Checked и Unchecked подписаться на событие Click, которое срабатывает при каждом нажатии.